# AWS Cognito first wait for user to verify email before updating it using updateUserAttributes()

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Some help on how do you prevent a Cognito user from locking themselves out when changing an email? i.e Only change the email in Cognito once it's verified for existing users updating an email.

If they enter a (wrong email i.e typo e.t.c) and we call Amplify.updateUserAttributes() Cognito registers that new email without waiting for the user to confirm it, locking the users out.

I've searched for ways to first have a 'temporary' new email which will only be active once a user verifies it and haven't seen one.